# Substitute for offAriabLabel and onAriableLabel for FluentUI Toggle?

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am trying to use a [FluentUI Toggle](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/toggle) with Windows Narrator. I am using custom `onText` and `offText`, so I would like the screen reader to read the approprate text instead of "on" and "off". However, according to the documentation, `onAriaLabel` and `offAriaLabel` seem to be obsolete.

> Warning: this API is now obsolete. Use ariaLabel for name, and let
> the metadata convey state.

I am using `ariaLabel` to set the name of the toggle, but what does it mean to "let the metadata convey state"? How can I have a screen reader read the custom text? Even if I try to use `onAriaLabel` and `offAriaLabel`, there seems to be an issue where the screen reader reads the label twice.